# How do I print and store regex (Regular Expressions) in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I need to be able to store and echo regular expressions. In my case the user enters the regex into a form and that exact sequence of characters needs to be echo-ed to the screen sometime later. The problem is that the echo changes the characters.

So for instance I have tried this

```
$regex = '(?<=amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)';
```

but when I echo it..

echo $regex;

I get...

```
((((amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=)
```

If I do this

$regex = htmlentities($regex);

I get this which helped with the missing  part of the regex but not the multiple ((((

```
((((amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>
```

htmlspecialchars did not help either.

How do I get it  to echo the variable exactly  as it is written? And what would I need to do to store them in MySQL and retrieve them exactly as written?

EDIT - in response to some observations below, I add a bit more detail. This new example was done on a PHP 7.1 server in the cloud, Centos 7 rendered using Chrome.

```
$regex = '(?<=amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)';

$page_elements_regex[1][0] = $regex;
$page_elements_regex[1][1] = addslashes($regex);
$page_elements_regex[1][2] = htmlspecialchars($regex);
$page_elements_regex[1][3] = htmlentities($regex);

echo "regex  " . $page_elements_regex[1][0] . "<BR>";
echo "addslashes  " . $page_elements_regex[1][1] . "<BR>";
echo "htmlspecialcharacters  " . $page_elements_regex[1][2] . "<BR>";
echo "htmlentities  " . $page_elements_regex[1][3] . "<BR>";
```

Results

```
regex ((((amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=)
addslashes ((((amount\\\">\\$)(.*?)(?=)
htmlspecialcharacters ((((amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)
htmlentities ((((amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)
```

It is also a big clue that if you take off the first ( like this

```
$regex = '?<=amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)';
```

The result removes the first a of amount!! Is it interpreting the regex instead of echoing it?

```
 ?(((mount\">\$)(.*?)(?=)
```

Comment: Side note: It appears you are trying to use regex to parse HTML (which also might be contributing to the difficulty in printing).  Use an XML parser instead.

Comment: Actually, no, I literally want to echo regex that has been generated in another program exactly as it is entered into a form. It's origin nor destination  are  part of the problem. In fact it could be any text sequence it is just that this  regex among others is the one giving me the issue.

Comment: What you are saying is not reproducible. `htmlspecialchars` would be the appropriate function rather than `htmlentities`, if you want to output this in an HTML context - but both work, and show the content of your variable as-is in this case. There are no characters missing, and no extra ((( either. From what little info you have given us, it is currently impossible to tell _where_ you messed up your data.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, and I feel a bit foolish about the answer. My bad.

Somewhere else in my code I had this

```
$regex[1] = '(?<=amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)';
$regex[2] = '(?<=amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)';
$regex[3] = '(?<=amount\">\$)(.*?)(?=</strong>)';
```

I have no idea why this gave the result it did, rather than a straight up error, but once removed it all is fine. The bottom line is that both htmlspecialcharacters and htmlentities give the right answer, Lesson learnt.  Check all the code, my mistake was in the use of arrays, defining $regex as an array and a variable, not as I first thought here.